# Create view with different names than the tables they are created from

Tags: sql, view

I have a question about creating views in general.

If I have one table "table1" that has two columns, "code" and "value" is it possible to create a view "view1" that has the same data as table1 but just renames the columns to something different like "table1.code" and "table1.value" ? I kno this is a pretty simple question but I havent found much on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alias the columns in the query behind your view.  For example, your query might be like below...

```
SELECT code as table1.code, value as table1.value FROM table1
```

The exact syntax for creating a view is different depending on the vendor, which you didn't include in your question.  But you can alias the columns in a query in almost any implementation, including SQL Server, Oracle, MySql, etc.

Using an alias is as simple as typing the AS keyword, followed by whatever you want to alias the column name as.

Comment: Great! Thanks! I needed this for those three flavors of SQL actually. :)

Comment: I worked on one project that was developed in Austria and the DB table names and column names were all in german.  So to make it easier, we created a view for every table, and aliased all the columns with english translated names.  That sounds close to what you're looking to do.

Comment: remeber though if you do this,. you will not be able to do select table1.code from view. The new names will need to have brackets around them when you use them because of the period.